# SyncRoot for IList

Tags: c#, collections

My code is old code which uses `ArrayList` to store elements of collection. I use the `m_objects.SyncRoot` for [locking purpose before delete the object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.syncroot.aspx):

```
        lock(m_objects.SyncRoot) 
        {
            m_objects.Remove(obj);

        }
```

The issue now is, I now want to change the type of  `m_objects` from `ArrayList` to `List<T>`, and I encounter problem with the above code. What is the equivalent of `List<T>`'s `SyncRoot`
?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this might be what you are looking for

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
lock (((IList)list).SyncRoot)
{
}
```

Found at [C# Generics Recipes—Replacing the ArrayList with Its Generic Counterpart](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Generics_Recipes%E2%80%94Replacing_the_ArrayList_with_Its_Generic_Counterpart)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the concept the SyncRoot is just an object used to lock. It is there just to save you from creating an object to lock. So it has to be the same to do

```
Object m_objectsLock = new Object();

lock(m_objectsLock) 
{
    m_objects.Remove(obj);

}
```

You have to be sure to use m_objectsLock everywhere where the SyncRoot is used.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the `SyncRoot` concept is outdated and wasn't used much anyway.
Most people went with a `lock(){}` block instead.

```
public class SomeClass {
  private readonly object listLock = new object();
  private readonly List<string> yourList = new List<string>();

  public void DeleteItem(string item) {
    lock (listLock) {
      yourList.Remove(item)
    }
  }
}
```